# SQL string concatenation, separated by ',' only when column is not null

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-concatenation

I want update string (`varchar`) column in my database. I want to concatenate ',' + value.

This is working, but I don't want to add ',' (comma) if value in database column is empty.

It does not make sense to have comma at beginning.

```
UPDATE ImportState
SET ClientValidationRemark = ClientValidationRemark + ',' + @ClientValidationRemark
WHERE Id=@ImportId
```

Of course I want add comma every time if value is not empty. Do you know any simple, clean way to do this? I always update one row, `@ImportId` is the primary key.

Comment: Is it possible for `@ClientValidationRemark` to be `NULL`?

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, let me start by saying that keeping delimited string in a single column is a terrible database design, with only one exception: when the data is never used in sql and is needed as a delimited string in the application. In over 16 years of programming, I've only one time  stored values like this, and it was exactly this scenario.

However, should you choose to store delimited values, here is something easy to do:

```
UPDATE ImportState
SET ClientValidationRemark = ISNULL(NULLIF(ClientValidationRemark, '') + ',', '') +
                             @ClientValidationRemark
WHERE Id=@ImportId
```

Taking advantage of the fact that concatenating strings to null values will result as null (Note: only when you use the [string concatenation operator (`+`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/string-concatenation-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), Not when you use the built in function [`concat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)), I've used `NULLIF` to convert empty string values in `ClientValidationRemark` to null, and then `ISNULL` to convert the `null + ', '`  back to an empty string.

Comment: Will this work in case when column is NOT NULL and when colum is NULL ?

Comment: It should work either way, since you are not inserting null to the column, unless, of course, the value of `@ClientValidationRemark` is null...

Comment: > concatenating strings to null values will result as null,
Ah ah, this is the key I was missing.

Comment: @Poutrathor in SQL Server, `declare @var varchar(100) =  'string' + null;` will result with `@var` being `null`.

Comment: I just check and CONCAT(NULL, 'Not Null') returns 'Not Null'. "CONCAT implicitly converts null values to empty strings." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 

So it's not an always rule that concatenating strings to null values will result as null.

Comment: @Poutrathor `concat` is not the same as using the concatenation operator `+` between string values. One of the things it does is implicit conversion to `varchar`/`nvarchar` and another thing is treating `null` as empty strings.  I've never mentioned the `concat` function in my answer, so I don't know how all of this is relevant - When using the string concatenation operator, you get the behavior I've described.

Comment: We could work on the phrasing. It matters to raise awareness of false friends.

Comment: @Poutrathor I've edited my answer. Hope that you don't find it confusing now.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an untested sample

```
UPDATE ImportState
SET ClientValidationRemark =
CASE ClientValidationRemark WHEN Null THEN @ClientValidationRemark
                            WHEN '' THEN @ClientValidationRemark
                            ELSE ClientValidationRemark + ',' + @ClientValidationRemark
END 
WHERE Id=@ImportId
```

Comment: I think he wants not `THEN NULL` but `THEN @ClientValidationRemark`.

Comment: I need, when NULL or Empty string THEN @ClientValidationRemark. Else is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

You can use `COALESCE`.

```
UPDATE ImportState
SET 
    ClientValidationRemark = 
           COALESCE(ClientValidationRemark + COALESCE(',' + @ClientValidationRemark,''), 
                    @ClientValidationRemark) 
WHERE Id=@ImportId
```